# Can someone explain the condition given in while loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I want to know what is the condition that is while loop checking in the code given below
**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    while (!printf("hello owrld"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lookup the documentation of `printf`

Comment: Unrelated: get into the habit of including a newline at the end of your prints: `printf("hello owrld\n");`

Comment: Has the printf documentation been helpful? https://documentation.help/C-Cpp-Reference/printf.html

Answer (score 1):

It is checking if what `printf()` returns (the number of characers printed, or a negative value that indicates error) is zero.

---

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function:

> The fprintf function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value
> if an output or encoding error occurred.

Quote from N1570 7.21.6.3 The printf function:

> The printf function is equivalent to fprintf with the argument stdout interposed
> before the arguments to printf.

Qote from N1570 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators:

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares
> unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type int.
> The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E).

Answer (score 0):

Basically printf() function returns the number of character in a string written inside double quotes as its return value so if there is ! ("negation") then any value other than 0 is considered 0 as a result. That's how the condition inside while loop is false.
I hope it's helpful.